# Web api is sending JSON object in wrong format

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am working with DevExtreme. I am trying receive JSON from web api server using ajax.

```
function getJSONfunction()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:999/api/CheckNotification?machinename=LENOVO-PC',
        type: "Get",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    })
```

I am expecting received from web api json object like this:

```
{"Result":"true"}
```

But problem is, web api is sending object like this:

```
"{\"Result\":\"true\"}"
```

And I can't see alert from getJSONfunction().

In web api "Get" function look like this:

```
public string Get(string machineName)
{
    int NotificationsNumber = NotificationsFunctions.CheckForNotifications(machineName);
    NotificationsResult result = new NotificationsResult();
    if(NotificationsNumber > 0)
    {
        result.Result = "true";
    }else
    {
        result.Result = "false";
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = js.Serialize(result);
    return json;
}
```

where "NotificationsResult" is a class

```
public class NotificationsResult
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

And my question is how can I received JSON object from api in correct format?

Comment: Just out of curiosity and to possibly help other answers, is there any reason why you're not using a 'bool' for the true/false values and instead using 'string'?

Comment: No, there is no any reasons ;). I will change this into bool variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your result is getting serialized twice, once by you, and again by the framework.

There is no need to *manually* serialize your class. If it's serializable, WebApi will serialize it for you once once you return it.

You can do that following instead:

```
public NotificationsResult Get(string machineName)
{
    int NotificationsNumber = NotificationsFunctions.CheckForNotifications(machineName);
    return new NotificationsResult
    {
        Result = NotificationsNumber > 0 ? "true" : "false";             
    };
}
```

Comment: I am sure that JSON is wrong, because when I am openning this json for example in notepad, i've got wrong result :/.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use JsonResult

```
public JsonResult Get(string machineName)
    {
        int NotificationsNumber = NotificationsFunctions.CheckForNotifications(machineName);
        NotificationsResult result = new NotificationsResult();
        if(NotificationsNumber > 0)
        {
            result.Result = "true";
        }else
        {
            result.Result = "false";
        }

        return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: I've got "The name Json does not exist in the current context" error. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Include missing assembly

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery.parseJSON(json) at client side you may get the result as you expected

Comment: JQuery does this for you if the data type is correct. See [jquery.ajax Section 'Data Types'](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).